# Change $PATH in android studio

Tags: android, path, swig

I'm trying to build a project that would run `swig` on build. However my swig is installed with homebrew, aka /usr/local/homebrew/bin/swig.

When I build it with Android Studio, it fails with error 2 (no such file). Now how can I change the `$PATH` variable globally in android studio?